# Find index corresponding between two different sized array lists with same total elements

Tags: arrays, numpy, chunks

How can corresponding array indices be found within two differently shaped arrays of arrays that are the same size?

For example, an array `x` of size 36 is split into 11 arrays.  Another array `y` of size 36 is split into 4 arrays.  Then some modifications happen on the 4 arrays making up `y`.

```
N  = 6 #some size param
x = np.zeros(N*N,dtype=np.int) #make empty array
s1 = np.array_split(x,11) #split array into arbitrary parts

y = np.random.randint(5, size=(N, N)) #make another same size array (and modify it)
s2 = np.array_split(y,4) #split array into different number of parts
```

Then iterating through the 4 arrays of `y`, I need to find the start index in the first array (`array_num`) of `s1`, to the end index of the last array of `s1` that the values in `s2` correspond to.

```
for sub_s2 in s2:
    array_num = ?
    s_idx = ?
    e_idx = ?

    s2_idx = ?
    e2_idx = ?

    #put the array into the correct ordered indexes of the other array
    s1[array_num][s_idx,e_idx] = sub_s2[s2_idx,e2_idx]

res = np.concatenate(s1)
```

I made this image to try and illustrate the issue.  In this case, 'data' means the size of x and y to start.  Then s1 and s2 are broken into different chunks, and the problem is finding the index within each chunk that the arrays in s2 correspond to. [image]

Answer (score 0):

Here is how to find the correct indices:

```
# create example use same data for both splits for easy validation
a = np.arange(36)

s1 = np.array_split(a, 11)
s2 = np.array_split(a, 4)

# recover absolute offsets of bit boundaries 
l1 = np.cumsum([0, *map(len,s1)])
l2 = np.cumsum([0, *map(len,s2)])

# find bits in s1 into which the first ...
start_n = l1[1:].searchsorted(l2[:-1], 'right')
# ... and last elements of bits of s2 fall
end_n = l1[1:].searchsorted(l2[1:]-1, 'right')

# find the corresponding indices into bits of s1
start_idx = l2[:-1] - l1[start_n]
end_idx = l2[1:]-1 - l1[end_n]

# check
[s[0] for s in s2]
# [0, 9, 18, 27]
[s1[n][i] for n, i in zip(start_n, start_idx)]
# [0, 9, 18, 27]
[s[-1] for s in s2]
# [8, 17, 26, 35]
[s1[n][i] for n, i in zip(end_n, end_idx)]
# [8, 17, 26, 35]
```